# compare arraylist with string

Tags: android

I want to compare two variables the first arraylist and the second is string

How can i convert the String to arrayList to compare those values in the variables

thank you in advance

Comment: You need to provide a lot more info here. What kind of comparison do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to understand your question, but if your String is like this "cat,dog,elephant" then you can use String.split(",") to get a String array, and then convert that to an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(myString.split(",")));
```